# Why do I get "TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"?

Tags: python, constructor, typeerror, positional-argument

I have some code like:

```py
class Pump:    
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")

    def getPumps(self):
        pass

p = Pump.getPumps()
print(p)
```

But I get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dom\Desktop\test\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    p = Pump.getPumps()
TypeError: getPumps() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Why doesn't `__init__` seem to be called, and what does this exception mean? My understanding is that `self` is passed to the constructor and methods automatically. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 588, accepted):

To use the class, first create an instance, like so:

```
p = Pump()
p.getPumps()
```

A full example:

```
>>> class TestClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print("init")
...     def testFunc(self):
...         print("Test Func")
... 
>>> testInstance = TestClass()
init
>>> testInstance.testFunc()
Test Func
```

Answer (score 102):

You need to initialize it first:

```
p = Pump().getPumps()
```

Answer (score 12):

Adding a `@classmethod` decorator to the method allows for calling it like `Pump.getPumps()`.

A class method receives the class as the implicit first argument, just like an instance method receives the instance.

```
class Pump:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")

    @classmethod
    def getPumps(cls):
        pass
```

Answer (score 8):

The `self` keyword in Python is analogous to `this` keyword in C++ / Java / C#.

In Python 2 it is done implicitly by the compiler (yes Python does compilation internally).
It's just that in Python 3 you need to mention it **explicitly** in the constructor and member functions. example:

```py
class Pump():
    # member variable
    # account_holder
    # balance_amount

    # constructor
    def __init__(self,ah,bal):
        self.account_holder = ah
        self.balance_amount = bal

    def getPumps(self):
        print("The details of your account are:"+self.account_number + self.balance_amount)

# object = class(*passing values to constructor*)
p = Pump("Tahir",12000)
p.getPumps()
```

Comment: It's not a keyword, just a convention.

Comment: What do you mean by *"In Python 2 it is done implicitly by the compiler"*? AFAIK Python 2 never set `self` implicitly.

Comment: This is not valid Python code. What are you trying to demonstrate exactly? To start, Python comments use `#`, not `//`; you don't need to declare member attributes at the class-level; and those pipes seem to be out-of-place.

Comment: *"In Python 2 it is done implicitly by the compiler"* citation needed.

Comment: There are many differences between Python 2.x and Python 3.x, even some that concern how classes work. This, however, is absolutely not one of them. Aside from that, the problem was **nothing to do with** explicit `self`. The problem is simply about **instantiating the class**.

Answer (score 6):

You can also get this error by prematurely taking PyCharm's advice to annotate a method @staticmethod.  Remove the annotation.

Comment: Another possibility in the neighborhood of this answer is if you declare a method as an `@staticmethod` and then include (or retain) `self` as the first positional argument..

Answer (score 2):

Remember 2 points

1. While **defining** the class **do not** enclose the class name by **()** bracket.

   ```
   class Pump:    
   def __init__(self):
   ```
2. Also while **instantiating** class by object **do not forget** to **use ()** bracket. Because only then above error is displayed.

- If you want to call method without instantiating the object then inline instantiating `Pump().getPumps()`
- But ideally best practice is to instantiate the object with short key  and then use that object instantiated to call the methods of the class, like

  ```
   p = Pump()
   p.getPumps()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

When **an instance method** had `self`, then I called it directly by class name as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def test(self): # <- With "self" 
        print("Test")

Person.test() # Here
```

And, when **a static method** had `self`, then I called it by object or directly by class name as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    @staticmethod
    def test(self): # <- With "self" 
        print("Test")

obj = Person()
obj.test() # Here

# Or

Person.test() # Here
```

So, I called the instance method with object as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def test(self): # <- With "self" 
        print("Test")

obj = Person()
obj.test() # Here
```

And, I removed `self` from the static method as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    @staticmethod
    def test(): # <- "self" removed 
        print("Test")

obj = Person()
obj.test() # Here

# Or

Person.test() # Here
```

Then, the error was solved:

```
Test
```

In detail, I explain about **instance method** in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python/74482579#74482579) for [**What is an "instance method" in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230482/what-is-an-instance-method-in-python) and also explain about [**@staticmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) and [**@classmethod**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) in [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python/74470227#74470227) for [**@classmethod vs @staticmethod in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

If skipping parentheses for the object declaration (typo), then exactly this error occurs.

```
# WRONG! will result in TypeError: getPumps() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
p = Pump
p.getPumps()
```

Do not forget the parentheses for the Pump object

```
# CORRECT!
p = Pump()
p.getPumps()
```

Comment: See also: [What does it mean when the parentheses are omitted from a function or method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933).

Answer (score 1):

This error may also be raised if a required positional argument for a function is not passed. For example the following triggers the error.

```py
def func(value, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

func()            # <--- TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
func(a=1, b=2)    # <--- TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

# passing the required arg solves the issue
func(30)          # <--- OK
func(3, a=1, b=2) # <--- OK
```

The above example is very simple but if `func()` was imported from a module, it would be less obvious. For example, numpy module's `allclose` function (which checks if two arrays are close enough) expects two positional arguments. If you pass the two arrays as a tuple/list, you'll get the TypeError in the title.

```py
import numpy as np
np.allclose(([1, 2], [1, 1]))  # <--- TypeError
np.allclose([1, 2], [1, 1])    # <--- OK
```

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE**

```
 class Person:
        def __init__(self, full_name, uuid, user_type, working_hours=None):
            self.full_name = full_name
            self.uuid = uuid
    
        def load_data(filename):
            print("Data")
           
        
        def load_readers(self):
            return self.load_data("readers.txt")
```

**AFTER**

```
class Person:
        def __init__(self, full_name, uuid, user_type):
            self.full_name = full_name
            self.uuid = uuid
            self.user_type = user_type
    
        def load_data(self, filename):
            print("Data")
           
        
        def load_readers(self):
            return self.load_data("readers.txt")
```

In my situation, the error was caused by a missing self keyword in the `load_data()` function, which was used in the `load_readers()` function.

Try to check if all your functions have the `self` keyword

**HOW I CALLED THE CLASS**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        person = Person("Foo", 1222, "READER")
        print(person.load_readers())
```

So instead of using the class name, first initiate the class object to call the function.