# adding dictionary values from class

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the class planets that stores in a dictionary Key which is the name of the planet, and value which is the size of the planet, and then add all the values in the dictionary and print it

this is my class

```
 class planets:
    def store(self, name, mass):
        aDict[self.name] = self.mass

    def add(self):
        return sum(aDict.values())


planets.store("Sun",50)

planets.store("Mercury",7)

print(planets.add())
```

I am expecting to get an answer of 57, however I am getting an error which is:

```
TypeError: store() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mass'
```

How to fix that problem?

Comment: `aDict[self.name] = self.mass` would fail as there are no name and mass fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pygame TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034714/pygame-typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`planets` is a class, `def store(self, name, mass):` is a instance method. You need to make a instance of `planets` first to use it's instance methods.

```
p = planets()
p.store("Sun",50)
p.store("Mercury",7)
print(p.add())
```

Second problem, you have to use `mass` to refer the parameter `mass` not `self.mess`. `self.mess` is a property of planets object. And, you need to initialize the `aDict` property in the `__init__` method. So you can define the class using below codes.

```
class planets:
    def __init__(self):
        self.aDict = {}

    def store(self, name, mass):
        self.aDict[name] = mass

    def add(self):
        return sum(self.aDict.values())
```

Comment: You are right, However I am still getting error which is : " AttributeError: 'planets' object has no attribute 'mass' "

Comment: The error actually sounds like invoking an instance method without an instance. Python would consider "Sun" to be self, 50 to be name and complain about missing the last (mass) argument.

Comment: @Mozein: Se my comment to  question. You are referencing absent fields in store() method. Use method arguments instead. Remove "self.".