# TypeError: attack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, typeerror

hi im getting this error

```
TypeError: attack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

and this is my code

```
class Enemmy :
    life = 3
    self = ""
    def attack(self):
        print ("ouch!!!!")
        self.life -= 1

    def checkLife(self):
        if self.life <= 0 :
            print ("dead")
        else:
            print (self.life)

enemy=Enemmy
enemy.attack()
```

i checked and looked most places says i forgot the self in the def attack 
or that i need to make an obj to put the class in 
im useing python 3.4 with py charm 
i actually got this code from a tutorial and i dont know what is my mistake

Comment: `enemy=Enemmy` -> `enemy=Enemmy()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 6):

You're not instantiating your `Enemy` class. You are creating a new reference to the class itself. Then when you try and call a method, you are calling it without an instance, which is supposed to go into the `self` parameter of `attack()`.

Change

```
enemy = Enemy
```

to

```
enemy = Enemy()
```

Also (as pointed out in by Kevin in the comments) your `Enemy` class should probably have an `init` method to initialise its fields. E.g.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = 3
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create and use an instance of the class, not the class itself:

```
enemy = Enemmy()
```

That instance is then accessible as `self`. If you don't have an instance, then it's missing and that's what the error message tells you.