# Orange Python script - parsing an ISO date

Tags: python, date, orange

I am trying to turn a series of ISO dates into equivalent timestamps:

```
from Orange.data import TimeVariable

unix_stamp = TimeVariable.parse('2020-12-31')

print(unix_stamp)
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'datestr'
```

What should I write?

For reference, the manual (https://docs.biolab.si//3/data-mining-library/reference/data.variable.html) reads:

> class Orange.data.TimeVariable(*args, have_date=0, have_time=0,
>   **kwargs)
>
> TimeVariable is a continuous variable with Unix epoch (1970-01-01
>   00:00:00+0000) as the origin...
>
> parse(datestr)
>
> Return datestr, a datetime provided in one of ISO 8601 formats, parsed
>   as a real number.

Comment: You need to create an instance of `TimeVariable` first, to call its `parse` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: attack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174847/typeerror-attack-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: @mkrieger the problem is the same (unistantiated class) but I would never have found out from the other question, without enough prior knowledge of Python. But my question is answered.