# Orange Python Script create custom timestamp (Orange Data Mining Windows 10)

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, orange

I am trying to achieve a script, which will create an Orange data table with just a single column containing a custom time stamp.

Usecase: I need a complete time stamp so I can merge some other csv files later on. I'm working in the [Orange GUI](https://orangedatamining.com/docs/) BTW and am not working in the actual python shell or any other IDE (in case this information makes any difference).

Here's what I have come up with so far:

```
From Orange.data import Domain, Table, TimeVariable
import numpy as np

domain = Domain([TimeVariable("Timestamp")])

# Timestamp from 22-03-08 to 2022-03-08 in minute steps
arr = np.arange("2022-03-08", "2022-03-15", dtype="datetime64[m]")

# Obviously necessary to achieve a correct format for the matrix
arr = arr.reshape(-1,1)

out_data = Table.from_numpy(domain, arr)
```

However the results do not match:

```
>>> print(arr)
[['2022-03-08T00:00']
 ['2022-03-08T00:01']
 ['2022-03-08T00:02']
 ...
 ['2022-03-14T23:57']
 ['2022-03-14T23:58']
 ['2022-03-14T23:59']]

>>> print(out_data)
[[27444960.0],
 [27444961.0],
 [27444962.0],
 ...
 [27455037.0],
 [27455038.0],
 [27455039.0]]
```

Obviously I'm missing something when handing over the data from numpy but I'm having a real hard time trying to understand the [documentation](https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-data-mining-library/en/latest/reference/data.variable.html).

I've also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61032357/orange-python-script-parsing-an-iso-date) which seems to tackle a similar issue, but I haven't figured out how to apply the solution on my problem.

I would be really glad if anyone could help me out here. Please try to use simple terms and concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the question, and apologies for the weak documentation of the `TimeVariable`.

In your code, you must change two things to work.
First, it is necessary to set whether the `TimeVariable` includes time and/or date data:

- `TimeVariable("Timestamp", have_date=True)` stores only date information -- it is analogous to `datetime.date`
- `TimeVariable("Timestamp", have_time=True)` stores only time information (without date) -- it is analogous to `datetime.time`
- `TimeVariable("Timestamp", have_time=True, have_date=True)` stores date and time -- it is analogous to `datetime.datetime`

You didn't set that information in your example, so both were `False` by default. For your case, you must set both to `True` since your attribute will hold the date-time values.

The other issue is that Orange's Table stores date-time values as UNIX epoch (seconds from 1970-01-01), and so also `Table.from_numpy` expect values in this format. Values in your current `arr` array are in minutes instead. I just transformed the `dtype` in the code below to seconds.

Here is the working code:

```
from Orange.data import Domain, Table, TimeVariable
import numpy as np

# Important: set whether TimeVariable contains time and/or date
domain = Domain([TimeVariable("Timestamp", have_time=True, have_date=True)])

# Timestamp from 22-03-08 to 2022-03-08 in minute steps
arr = np.arange("2022-03-08", "2022-03-15", dtype="datetime64[m]").astype("datetime64[s]")

# necessary to achieve a correct format for the matrix
arr = arr.reshape(-1,1)
out_data = Table.from_numpy(domain, arr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response Primoz. You are my hero of the day - thanks to your support I will be able to save a lot of time! Kind regards