# Calling on a class

Tags: python, geopy

I'm using geopy and have a question on why an error is coming up.

This code sample is from the one provided at [github](https://github.com/geopy/geopy#geocoding). It works as mentioned

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()

location = geo.geocode("NY")

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

How come the code below provides an error? What's the reason behind it?

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim as geo

location = geo.geocode("NY")

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

The error provided by the second code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/so2.py", line 5, in <module>
    location = geo.geocode("NY")
TypeError: geocode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534363/3337714) might resolve your query.

Comment: in the first code sample you create object Nomination, then in second sample you don't, so it expects two arguments from you `self` and some string I believe. And you are passing only one.

Comment: Thank you, that explains the reason quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate class (create object)

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim as geo

location = geo().geocode("NY")

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

Comment: @ThePavolIC did you just copy SukritKalra answer's from the comment? Interesting!

Comment: Not really, you have posted a link to answer. I think I gave the answer. But I didn't refresh the page while writing comment so I didn't see other posts

Comment: That means that the question is duplicate and it already has a answer. You are providing repeating solutions instead of re-directing?.