# pytorch Network.parameters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

There's a problem when I call Network.parameters() in pytorch in this line in my main function:
optimizer = optim.SGD(Network.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

I get the error code:

`TypeError: parameters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

My network is defined in this class

```
class Network(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Network, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 5)
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 512)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 640)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(640, 3756)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 64 * 5 * 5)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

Pretty sure that I imported all torch modules correctly.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When doing `Network.parameters()` you are calling the **static method** `parameters`.

But, `parameters` is an **instance method**.

So you have to instansiate `Network` before calling `parameters`.

```
network = Network()
optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

Or, if you only needs Network first this particular line:

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(Network().parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

Comment: `parameters()` is a library function in Torch. Can't change it. And semantically, you wouldn't want to—the function returns the parameters of a *particular* nn.Module.

Comment: @aryamccarthy ho, yes. I updated my anwser, thx. Your one is surely the one, but I prefere to not remove my answer to explicit static / instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need a particular `Network` instance, not just the `Network` *class*.

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(Network().parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

Note the parentheses to create an instance of the `Network`.