# TypeError: movement() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, self

i dont know what to do, ive googled it and looked at other answers but nothing ive tried is working, im trying to create a sprite, and then move it, i was able to get the sprite to move but it would immiedietly go back to its starting position. after inti this class i get NameError: name 'image' is not defined

```
import pygame
import os
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((448, 576))
done = False

y = 320
x = 216

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
PACMANSPRITE = pygame.image.load("pacman.png").convert_alpha()

class pacman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        self.image = image
        self.y=y
        self.x=x
        screen.blit((image), (x,y))


    def movement(self):
        pressed= pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y=y-10
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y=y+10
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x=x-10
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x=x+10
        screen.blit(image, (x,y))

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))


        pacman(PACMANSPRITE, x ,y)
        pacman.movement()



        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called the method *directly on the class*:

```
pacman.movement()
```

Perhaps you wanted to store the instance you created on the line preceding that call?

```
sprite = pacman(PACMANSPRITE, x ,y)
sprite.movement()
```

You probably want to create *one* instance outside of your loop:

```
sprite = pacman(PACMANSPRITE, x ,y)
while not done:
    # ...
    sprite.movement()
```

Next, your `movement` method references a global `image` variable that is not defined; presumably you meant the `image` attribute on the instance, referenceable with `self.image`:

```
def movement(self):
    # ...
    screen.blit(self.image, (x,y))
```

Comment: it then tells me image is not defined  NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Comment: @CallumDonovan: it's `self.image`, not `image`.

Comment: you wouldnt be able to quikcly help me out with something else would you? the self.y and self.x arent increaing, the sprite will move for a frame then go back

Comment: That'd be a new question, perhaps.

Comment: it wont let me ask again for 90 minutes, im new here, thanks for the reply though