# Getting error missing postional argument self

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do i get the error missing required positional argument self when i call 
inp() on the object.

```
process=[]
class Process:
    def __init__(self):
        self.no=no
        self.at=at
        self.bt=bt
    def inp(self):
        ar=int(input('Enter arrival time'))
        bt=int(input('Enter burst time'))



x=int(input('Enter the no. of processes'))
for i in range(x):
    process.append(Process)
    q.no=i

for x in process:
    x.inp()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: What's `q`? Why use `x` in 2 different contexts? What's `no`, `at`, `bt` in `__init__`? Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I have to admit, I did not wrote that much python code in my live, so please don't be so censorious, if I used wrong terminology.

**But** as far as I know you are try to call the `inp()` method as a static method, because the `x` in

```
for x in process:
    x.inp()
```

isn't a new instance of the type `Process`. It is just the type `Process`, because you add the type `Process` to your array and not a new instance.

```
for i in range(x):
    process.append(Process)
```

---

*So let us say the user enters `5` as the number of processes. Now your for loop will run five times and add items to your `process` array. This array will now look like:*

```
process = [[0:Process] [1:Process] [2:Process] [3:Process] [4:Process]]
```

*which leads that you call five times `Process.inp()` as a static method in*

```
for x in process:
    x.inp()
```

*instead of an object method like*

```
p1.inp()
p2.inp()
...
p5.inp()
```

---

To fix this issue you could change your code to

```
for i in range(x):
    q = Process()
    process.append(q)
    q.no=i
```

and call later on

```
for x in process:
    x.inp()
```

---

But this will leads to another error, since you have defined `_init__(self)`
and try to set three properties you did not defined in the `__init__`signature.

So you could remove `def __init__` or add these parameter:

```
def __init__(self, no, at, bt):
    self.no=no
    self.at=at
    self.bt=bt
```

and create a new object with

```
q = Process(1, 2, 3)
```

---

At least I guess there is a little typo in your `inp()` method. Did you really want to set `ar`? I guess you mean `self.at`.

Comment: Yes,it's actually self.at. And thanks fixed it.But why x isn't the object i want to call inp() upon.

Comment: @PrajwalPathak: _But why x isn't the object i want to call inp() upon_. I try to express myself a little bit clearer. The `x` you are calling within your `for x in process:` is only an object of the __Type__ `Process` not a __new instance__ of this type. So if we assume the `x` within your `for i in range(x):  process.append(Process)` is _5_. You will add five times an object of the type `Process` to your `process` array and not five separate objects _`p1, p2, ...`_. So I presumed to think you want to call `x` as an instance instead of the type. I hope this clarified it a little bit better.