# How do I use one object from separate class in another class's method?

Tags: python, oop, methods

Beginner so please bear with me.  I am trying to call an object from one class into the method of another.  But I get a 'missing 1 required positional argument:' error. And when I play with the code I do not get any closer to a solution.

I removed "self" from the method to align the chore but then self.workload is not defined.  I then added the object in twice (ch1,ch1) and got an error the error Chore' object has no attribute 'workload'.  I played with (w1,ch1) and got the error that Workload has no attribute workload.

```
class Chore:

    def __init__ (self, ch_name, value=1, completion=True):
        self.ch_name = ch_name
        self.value = value
        self.completion = completion    

class Workload:

    def __init__ ():
        self.workload = []
        self.totalchores = 0


    def add_chore (self,chore):
        self.workload.append(chore)
        self.totalchores+=1

ch1=Chore('pick up')
w1=Workload
w1.add_chore(ch1)
```

I expect to have c1 appended to a empty list.

TypeError: add_chore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chore'

Comment: Always try to show the whole traceback. Anyway, almost certainly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17534345/1531971 (You probably need to instantiate a `Workload` not assign a variable to the type?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't instantiate Workload.

```
w1 = Workload()
```

Comment: thanks.  feels like I shouldn't have wasted anyones time for a simple oversight but I was really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as Daniel said, you didn't instantiate Workload. Also in the **init** you are using self to initiate workload and totalchore, then, as you are not recieving it for parameter, those variables are going  to nowhere.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.