# Error while calling python function, TypeError: returnbook() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I have created a python program where customers can return book and borrow book from Library, while executing I gets error * TypeError: borrow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' *

What changes I should make to execute the program successfully ?

I will call returnbook() function initially as the library have no books at present.

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.availablebook = availablebook
    def reducebook(self,book):
        if book in self.availablebook:
            self.availablebook.remove(book)
            print('book is removed')
    def addbook(self,book):
        self.availablebook.append(book)
        print('book added')

class Customer:
    def borrow(self):
        print('enter book')
        book = input()
        Library.reducebook(book)
    def returnbook(self):
        print('enter book')
        book = input()
        Library.addbook(book)

while True:
    print('enter 1 for add book,2 for borrow book,3 to exit')
    self.x = int(input())
    if(x==1):
        Customer.borrow()
    elif(x==2):
        Customer.returnbook()
    else:
        print('exiting')
        quit()
```

Comment: I have done the later and it worked, Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: I did both way in which called class itself and in other way I made instance of class and called on the instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an *instance* of the `Customer` class, do not use the class directly:

```
customer = Customer()
customer.borrow()
customer.returnbook()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code :

1. `self.x` is not an attribute from a class. You can just write `x`.
2. You have to add the `availablebook` variable as an input of **init** function
3. You get a missing argument because you do not create your `Library` and `Customer` classes the good way. You can write `Library([]).borrow()` if you consider adding `availablebook` input, else just write `Library().borrow()`.

I think the best is to create a library before you loop : `my_lib = Library([])`
Then add a library input in your `Customer` functions in order to edit the library you want and hence avoid creating a new library each time.

Here is the code I would suggest you :

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, availablebook):
        self.availablebook = availablebook

    def reducebook(self, book):
        if book in self.availablebook:
            self.availablebook.remove(book)
            print('book is removed')

    def addbook(self,book):
        self.availablebook.append(book)
        print('book added')

class Customer:
    def borrow(self, library):
        print('enter book')
        book = input()
        library.reducebook(book)

    def returnbook(self, library):
        print('enter book')
        book = input()
        library.addbook(book)

my_lib = Library([])
while True:
    print('enter 1 for add book,2 for borrow book,3 to exit')
    x = int(input())

    if(x==1):
        Customer().borrow(my_lib)

    elif(x==2):
        Customer().returnbook(my_lib)

    else:
        print('exiting')
        quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

`availablebook` should be a list in `__init__` function.

```
self.availablebook = []
```

Also, Modify your `while` loop.

```
while True:
    print('enter 1 for add book,2 for borrow book,3 to exit')
    x = int(input())
    if(x==1):
        Customer().borrow()
    elif(x==2):
        Customer().returnbook()
    else:
        print('exiting')
        quit()
```