# Panda3D: TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, panda3d

I'm running into some problems where it returns:

`TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Here is the Code:

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase

class MyGame(ShowBase):
def __init__(self):
    super.__init__()


Game = MyGame
Game.run()
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate an object from a class in python, you have to use brackets. Like when you call a function.

```
Game = MyGame() # add brackets after MyGame
```

Answer (score -1):

First write:

```
from direct.showbase.Showbase import Showbase
anyvariable = Showbase()
class MyGame(anyvariable):
```

And then add the rest of your code here onwards.