# How to get the value of a checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a checkbutton in my program but when I click the checkbox, it gives me the following error: TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Below is the code along with the related function. When I check the check box, it is supposed to take off the tax in the taxe field.

```
def getreservation():
global arrivaldtee
global my_box
global conf
global laste
global firste
global addresse
global citye
global statee
global zipe
global phonee
global emaile
global arrivale
global departe
global dayse
global adultse
global childrene
global roomnum
global ratee
global taxe
global dailye
global staye
global rateplancombo
global paymente
global rateplane
global checksmoke
global checkpet
global notese
global ide
global confnume
global var3
global var10
global var13





greserve = Toplevel()
greserve.title('Retrieve Reservations')
greserve.state('zoomed')
#greserve.geometry("1400x800+250+50")
greserve.configure(bg='#AFEEEE')

now = dt.datetime.now()
newdate = now + timedelta(days=1)
diff = newdate - now
diff2 = str(diff)


labelintro = Label(greserve, text="Retrieve Reservation", bg="#AFEEEE")
labelintro.config(font=("Times New Roman", 16))
labelintro.place(x=10, y=0)

last = Label(greserve, text="Last", bg="#AFEEEE")
last.place(x=35, y=30)
laste = Entry(greserve, width=30)
laste.place(x=70, y=30)

first = Label(greserve, text="First", bg="#AFEEEE")
first.place(x=35, y=50)
firste = Entry(greserve, width=30)
firste.place(x=70, y=50)

address = Label(greserve, text="Address", bg="#AFEEEE")
address.place(x=16, y=70)
addresse = Entry(greserve, width=50)
addresse.place(x=70, y=70)

city = Label(greserve, text="City", bg="#AFEEEE")
city.place(x=35, y=90)
citye = Entry(greserve, width=40)
citye.place(x=70, y=90)

state = Label(greserve, text="State", bg="#AFEEEE")
state.place(x=320, y=90)
statee = Entry(greserve, width=20)
statee.place(x=355, y=90)

zip = Label(greserve, text="Zip Code", bg="#AFEEEE")
zip.place(x=15, y=110)
zipe = Entry(greserve, width=10)
zipe.place(x=70, y=110)

phone = Label(greserve, text="Phone", bg="#AFEEEE")
phone.place(x=27, y=130)
phonee = Entry(greserve, width=20)
phonee.place(x=70, y=130)

email = Label(greserve, text="Email", bg="#AFEEEE")
email.place(x=27, y=150)
emaile = Entry(greserve, width=50)
emaile.place(x=70, y=150)

line = Label(greserve, text="=======================================================", bg="#AFEEEE")
line.place(x=0, y=170)

arrival = Label(greserve, text="Arrival Date", bg="#AFEEEE")
arrival.place(x=33, y=190)
arrivale = Entry(greserve, width=20)
arrivale.place(x=110, y=190)
arrivale.bind("<Button-1>", aexample1)
# dayss = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") + 1

depart = Label(greserve, text="Departure Date", bg="#AFEEEE")
depart.place(x=15, y=210)
departe = Entry(greserve, width=20)
departe.place(x=110, y=210)
departe.bind("<Button-1>", example1)

days = Label(greserve, text="Days", bg="#AFEEEE")
days.place(x=70, y=230)
rvar11 = DoubleVar()
dayse = Entry(greserve, textvariable=rvar11, width=20)
dayse.delete(0, END)
dayse.place(x=110, y=230)

adults = Label(greserve, text="Adults", bg="#AFEEEE")
adults.place(x=62, y=250)
adultse = Entry(greserve, width=20)
adultse.place(x=110, y=250)

children = Label(greserve, text="Children", bg="#AFEEEE")
children.place(x=54, y=270)
childrene = Entry(greserve, width=20)
childrene.place(x=110, y=270)



options = [
    "Select Room",
]
conn = sqlite3.connect('roominventory.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM rooms")
records = c.fetchall()

for record in records:
    if record[3] != "N":
        addie = record[0:2]
        options.append(addie)

room = Label(greserve, text="Room", bg="#AFEEEE")
room.place(x=67, y=290)
roomnum = Entry(greserve, width=20)
roomnum.place(x=110, y=290)

checkincombbo = ttk.Combobox(greserve, width=17, value=options)
checkincombbo.place(x=245, y=290)
checkincombbo.current(0)
checkincombbo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comboroom)

ratel = Label(greserve, text="Rate", bg="#AFEEEE")
ratel.place(x=75, y=310)
ratee = Entry(greserve, width=20)
ratee.place(x=110, y=310)
ratee.bind("<Return>", changerate)

tax = Label(greserve, text="Tax", bg="#AFEEEE")
tax.place(x=80, y=330)
taxe = Entry(greserve, width=20)
taxe.place(x=110, y=330)

var13 = IntVar
checktax = Checkbutton(greserve, bg="#AFEEEE", command=rtaxselect, variable=var13)
checktax.place(x=55, y=330)
checktax.select()

daily = Label(greserve, text="Daily Amount", bg="#AFEEEE")
daily.place(x=27, y=350)
dailye = Entry(greserve, width=20)
dailye.place(x=110, y=350)

stay = Label(greserve, text="Stay Amount", bg="#AFEEEE")
stay.place(x=30, y=370)
staye = Entry(greserve, width=20)
staye.place(x=110, y=370)

options2 = [
    "Select Rate Plan",
    "RACK",
    "AAA",
    "Senior",
    "Government",
    "Trucker",
    "---",
    "---",
    "---",

]

rateplan = Label(greserve, text="Rate Plan", bg="#AFEEEE")
rateplan.place(x=50, y=390)
rateplane=Entry(greserve, width=20)
rateplane.place(x=110, y=390)

rateplancombo = ttk.Combobox(greserve, width=17, value=options2)
rateplancombo.place(x=245, y=390)
rateplancombo.current(0)
rateplancombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", rateplan)

payment = Label(greserve, text="Payment", bg="#AFEEEE")
payment.place(x=50, y=410)
paymente = Entry(greserve, width=20)
paymente.place(x=110, y=410)

var10 = IntVar()
checksmoke = Checkbutton(greserve, text="Smoker", bg="#AFEEEE", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var10,
                         command=selectsmoke)
checksmoke.place(x=105, y=440)

var3 = IntVar()
checkpet = Checkbutton(greserve, text="Pet", bg="#AFEEEE", command=petbox, variable=var3)
checkpet.place(x=105, y=470)

line2 = Label(greserve, text="=======================================================", bg="#AFEEEE")
line2.place(x=0, y=490)

my_box = Listbox(greserve, height=19, width=125)
my_box.place(x=600, y=180)
my_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", checkinreservation)



options5 = [
    "Select Payment",
    "Visa",
    "Master Card",
    "Discover",
    "American Exp.",
    "Diners",
    "Cash",
    "Travelers Check",
    "Personal Check"

]

paymentcombo = ttk.Combobox(greserve, width=17, value=options5)
paymentcombo.place(x=245, y=410)
paymentcombo.current(0)
# paymentcombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", payselect)

notes = Label(greserve, text="NOTES:", bg="#AFEEEE")
notes.place(x=10, y=520)
notese = Entry(greserve, width=73)
notese.place(x=10, y=540)

id = Label(greserve, text="ID", bg="#AFEEEE")
id.place(x=40, y=565)
ide=Entry(greserve, width=10)
ide.place(x=60, y=565)

confnum=Label(greserve, text="Conf. #", bg="#AFEEEE")
confnum.place(x=10, y=585)
confnume = Entry(greserve, width=10)
confnume.place(x=60, y=585)

checkin = Button(greserve, text="Check In", command=checkinreserve)
checkin.place(x=1300, y=500)


update = Button(greserve, text="Update Reservation", command=updatereserve)
update.place(x=1150, y=500)

ext = Button(greserve, text="Exit-->", command=greserve.destroy)
ext.place(x=1090, y=500)

arrivaldte = Label(greserve, text="Arrival Date", bg="#AFEEEE")
arrivaldte.place(x=600, y=160)

arrivaldtee =Entry(greserve, width=20)
arrivaldtee.place(x=675, y=160)
arrivaldtee.bind("<Button-1>", rexample1)

search=Button(greserve, text="Search....", command=searcharrival)
search.place(x=800, y=155)

searchall = Button(greserve, text="Search All", command=searchallres)
searchall.place(x=875, y=155)

searchconf = Label(greserve, text="Confirmation#", bg="#AFEEEE")
searchconf.place(x=980, y=160)

conf = Entry(greserve, width=20)
conf.place(x=1070, y= 160)

confbtn = Button(greserve, text="Go...", command=searchconfn)
confbtn.place(x=1200, y=155)
```

def rtaxselect():

```
print(var13)
if var13.get() == 0:
    taxe.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: What is greserve?

Comment: `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self`.Try to post a minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate IntVar first. I.e. (Note the **()** after the IntVar)

```
var13 = IntVar()
```

Comment: A very similar problem with a solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534363

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help my particular problem.

Comment: Could you provide the complete code? As a bare minimum the definition of IntVar
Unless .get() is a static method, you need to instantiate the IntVar.

Comment: When I click the check button, I print the value and it prints the following:  <class 'tkinter.IntVar'>

Comment: You need to put () after IntVar.
So don't do: var13 = IntVar, do var13 = IntVar() instead

Comment: I did that and instead of printing 1 or 0 it prints:  PY_VAR1

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I changed from TopLevel()   to Tk()  Why that makes a difference I don't know but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I changed from TopLevel() to Tk() Why that makes a difference I don't know but it worked.