# Python won't recognize parameter in a function

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

I have created an object an included a function with 3 parameters, however, the program won't pick up my last parameter dy.

The code

```
class blaster(object):

    def __init__(self,x,y,r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = r
        self.xvelocity = 5
        self.yvelocity = 0
        self.blastercount = 0
        self.isblasting = False
        self.xarray = []
        self.yarray = []
        self.xcounter = []
        self.ycounter = []
    def initiate_blast(self,xx,yy,dx,dy):
        self.xarray.append(int(mn.x))
        self.yarray.append(int(mn.y))
        self.xcounter.append(int(dx))
        self.ycounter.append(int(dy))
```

The function gets called:

```
blaster.initiate_blast(troop.x,troop.y,5,5)
```

The output:

```
TypeError: initiate_blast() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dy'
```

Comment: You probably redefined *initiate\_blast* below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 2):

`initiate_blast` is defined as an *instance* method, and you're calling it on the *class*.

Therefore there's no implicit `self` parameter being passed in, so you're calling this:

```py
blaster.initiate_blast(self=troop.x, xx=troop.y, yy=5, dx=5)
```

Even if the call itself didn't blow up, it'd explode on the very first line as `self` would be nonsense without an `xarray` attribute.

It's extremely bad form to name "proper" classes in lowercase incidentally. It's OK for some builtins and class-based decorators or the like, but that's not the case here, `blaster` is obviously intended as an actual type, not as an arbitrary callable which just happens to be a class.