# hello i have wriiten this program for simpe notebook, but when i pass values to new_note function i recieve this error

Tags: python, class, object

```
TypeError: new_note() missing 1 required positional argument: 'memo'
```

Code:

```
import datetime
# Store the next available id for all new notes
last_id = 0
class Note:
    '''Represent a note in the notebook. Match against a
    string in searches and store tags for each note.'''

    def __init__(self, memo,tags=''):
        '''initialize a note with memo and optional
        space-separated tags. Automatically set the note's
        creation date and a unique id.'''

        self.memo = memo
        self.tags = tags
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()
        global last_id
        last_id += 1
        self.id = last_id

    def match(self,filter):
        '''Determine if this note matches the filter
        text. Return True if it matches, False otherwise.
        Search is case sensitive and matches both text and
        tags.'''
        return filter in self.memo or filter in self.tags
```

---

```
from notes2 import Note
    class Notebook:
        '''Represent a collection of notes that can be tagged,
        modified, and searched.'''
        def __init__(self,memo,tags = ' '):
            '''Initialize a notebook with an empty list.'''
            self.notes = []
        def new_note(self,memo, tags=''):
            '''Create a new note and add it to the list.'''
            self.notes.append(Note(memo, tags))
        def modify_memo(self, note_id, memo):
            '''Find the note with the given id and change its
            memo to the given value.'''
            for note in self.notes:
                if note.id == note_id:
                    note.memo = memo
                    break
        def modify_tags(self, note_id, tags):
            '''Find the note with the given id and change itsort
            tags to the given value.'''
            for note in self.notes:
                if note.id == note_id:
                    note.tags = tags
                    break
        def search(self, filter):
            '''Find all notes that match the given filter
            string.'''
            return [note for note in self.notes if note.match(filter)]

    n= Notebook
    n.new_note("hello")
```

Comment: You must instantiate the class by calling it like a function and then work with the created object.

Comment: Change `n= Notebook` -> `n= Notebook()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)