# In, selenium automation with python, for webdriver_manager.chrome and ChromeDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm getting below error

```
**driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager.install())
```

TypeError: install() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

Process finished with exit code 1

and my code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager



browserName = 'chrome'
if browserName == 'chrome':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager.install())

elif browserName == 'firefox':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

elif browserName == 'safari':
    driver= webdriver.safari()
else :
    driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())'''
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to instantiate the class before using it like the below:

```
p= ChromeDriverManager()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=p.install())
```

similarly you can do the same for other browsers as well

refer: [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)
for better understanding