# Can I access an instance-variable using a @classmethod?

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method

```
class MyClass:
    __module_attr: str = "module text value"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__instance_attr: str = "instance text value"

    @classmethod
    def cls_modify(cls):
        cls.__module_attr = "class text value"

    @classmethod
    def cls_display(cls):
        print(cls.__module_attr)
```

Suppose, I want to print the value of `__instance_attr` inside `cls_display()`.

How can I do that?

Comment: What happens if you put it's declaration next to `__module_attr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The class method is not given a reference to the instance object so its data is unavailable. Python generates the first parameter for instance and class methods for you. For instance methods, its a reference to instance data. For class methods, its a reference to the class object itself. If you don't need either of those things, static methods don't get any special first parameter.

In all three cases, the call looks the same. Nothing special is needed by the caller to tell you the method type. The caller need not know. And this is the point of the different types. The implementer chooses the type based on the data that's needed, but doesn't have to bother the user about it.

Comment: @user366312 Static methods are not passed an instance of anything. They are just functions stored in the class namespace. You won’t be able to access class or instance attributes

Comment: @user366312 No because that’s not your question and I’m sure there is a duplicate question already

Comment: @user366312 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65429073/235698