# How to use self in an abstract class implementation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, abc, python-class

I'm working on a project using abstract classes in Python (specifically, the abc module).

I have a few implementations of this abstract class, which have their own constructors and need to use `self`.

This is what my code looks like, but simplified:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sublinks = [] # not meant to be passed in, that's why it isn't an argument in __init__
    
    @classmethod
    def display(cls):
        print(cls.get_contents())
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get_contents():
        pass

class ImplementationOne(Base):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get_contents(self):
        return "The url was: " + url

class ImplementationTwo(Base):
    def get_contents():
        return "This does not need a url"

test_one = ImplementationOne("https://google.com")
test_two = ImplementationTwo()

test_one.display()
```

When I run this, however, I get the error `TypeError: get_contents() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

I figured that this is because `get_contents()` in ImplementationOne takes `self`, but it's not specified in the abstract method.

So, if I changed:

```
@abstractmethod
def get_contents():
    pass
```

to

```
@abstractmethod
def get_contents(self):
    pass
```

But I get the same error.

I've tried many combinations, including putting `self` as an argument to every occurrence or `get_contents`, and passing in `cls` to `get_contents` in the abstract class - but no luck.

So, pretty much, how can I use the `self` keyword (aka access attributes) in only some implementations of an abstract method, that's called within a class method in the abstract class itself.

Also, on a side note, how can I access `self.sublinks` from within all implementations of BaseClass, while having its values different in each instance of an implementation?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self/17534363) help?

Comment: I wanted to do something similar like you and I also had a misunderstanding too. So even though the question may seem wrong, I asked myself the same question so it's quite useful for lost people like me to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. One is that the `@classmethod` decorator should only be used when you need it to be called on a class.

Example:

```
class ImplementationOne:
    @classmethod
    def display(cls):
        print(f'The class name is {cls.__name__}.')

ImplementationOne.display()
```

There is nothing special about the name `self`. It's just what is used by everyone to refer to the instance. In python the instance is implicitly handed to the first argument of the class unless you have a `@classmethod` decorator. In that case the class is handed as the first argument.

That is why you are getting the `TypeError`. Since you are calling the method on the instance `test_one.display()` you are essentially calling it as an instance method. Since you need to access the instance method `get_contents` from within it that is what you want. As a `classmethod` you wouldn't have access to `get_contents`.

That means you need both the ABC and `ImplementationOne` to have those methods implemented as instance methods.

Since it is now an instance method on the ABC  it also should be an instance method in `ImplementationTwo`.

Your other question was how to get `self.sublinks` as an attribute in both subclasses.
Since your are overriding `__init__` in `ImplementationOne` you need to call the parent class's `__init__` as well. You can do this by using `super()` to call the Super or Base class's methods.

```
class ImplementationOne(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        super().__init__()
```

Full working code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sublinks = []
    
    def display(self):
        print(self.get_contents())
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get_contents(self):
        pass

class ImplementationOne(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        super().__init__()

    def get_contents(self):
        return "The url was: " + self.url

class ImplementationTwo(BaseClass):
    def get_contents(self):
        return "This does not need a url"

test_one = ImplementationOne("https://google.com")
test_two = ImplementationTwo()

test_one.display()
test_two.display()
print(test_one.sublinks)
```

Comment: Very helpful explanations, thank you!