# How to execute a program with a class?

Tags: python, class

I'm new to python...so i was trying to run this code but the error says **menu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'** after the while statement. However, when i added *self* the error says **name 'self' is not defined**. What is the proper way to run this code?

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 1000
    
    def menu(self):
        print("Options:")
        print("1. Make Deposit")
        print("2. Make a Withdrawl")
        print("3. Obtain Balance")
        print("4. Quit")        

    def deposit(self):
        depositAmount = float(input("Enter amount of deposit: "))
        print("Deposit processed")
        self.balance += depositAmount
    
    def withdrawl(self):
        withdrawalAmount = float(input("Enter amount of withdrawl: "))
        if withdrawalAmount > 1500:
            print("Denied. Maximum withdrawl is $1,500.00")        
        elif withdrawalAmount > self.balance:
            print("Insufficient balance")
        else:
            self.balance -= withdrawalAmount
        
    def balance(self):
        print(self.balance)
    
    def exit(self):
        quit()
    
def main():
    while True:
        Account.menu()
        choice = int(input("Make a selection from the options menu: "))
        
        if choice == 1:
            Account.deposit()

        elif choice == 2:
            Account.withdrawl()

        elif choice == 3:
            Account.balance()
        
        elif choice == 4:
            quit()
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need to create an `Account` instance before calling the methods. For example: `account1 = Account()`. Then use `account1.deposit()` etc...

Comment: Why is this tagged `callback`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems like you fundmentally misunderstand how to use classes. I suggest looking at the official [tutorial on the subject](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Suffice it to say, you need to create an instance and use those methods on the instance. Just like `list` objects. `list` is just a class. When you do `mylist = list()` you are instantiating a list object. Then when you use `mylist.append(42)`, you are using the `list.append` method on the list instance.

Comment: *Be carefule*. your `Account` class has an instance variable, `self.balance`, but you also define a method, `def balance(self)`, that means your instance variable will *shadow* your method. don't name methods the same name as instance variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. You need to create an instance of the Account class. You also need to change the balance method's name because you already have "self.balance"

`class Account():
def **init**(self):
self.balance = 1000

```
def menu(self):
    print("Options:")
    print("1. Make Deposit")
    print("2. Make a Withdrawl")
    print("3. Obtain Balance")
    print("4. Quit")        

def deposit(self):
    depositAmount = float(input("Enter amount of deposit: "))
    print("Deposit processed")
    self.balance += depositAmount

def withdrawl(self):
    withdrawalAmount = float(input("Enter amount of withdrawl: "))
    if withdrawalAmount > 1500:
        print("Denied. Maximum withdrawl is $1,500.00")        
    elif withdrawalAmount > self.balance:
        print("Insufficient balance")
    else:
        self.balance -= withdrawalAmount
    
def showBalance(self):
    print(self.balance)

def exit(self):
    quit()
```

account = Account()

def main():
while True:
account.menu()
choice = int(input("Choose an option: "))

```
    if choice == 1:
        account.deposit()

    elif choice == 2:
        account.withdrawl()

    elif choice == 3:
        account.showBalance()
    
    elif choice == 4:
        quit()
        break
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()`