# Calling function from another function in the same class

Tags: python

I know that in order for my function `def get_moveup(self)` to call my `def get_position(self)` function, I do `self.get_position()`. When I try executing my `def get_moveup(self)` by using `knobA.get_moveup()` I keep getting `TypeError: get_moveup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` How would I fix this?

```py
class knobA(knob):
    def __init__(self, position, moveup, movedown, moveleft, moveright):
        super().__init__()
        self.position = position
        self.moveup = moveup
        self.movedown = movedown
        self.moveleft = moveleft 
        self.moveright = moveright 
    
    def get_position(self):
        print("G0 X50 Y50 Z50 \r\n")

    def get_moveup(self):
        self.get_position()
    
    def get_movedown(self):
        return self.movedown
    
    def get_moveleft(self):
        return self.moveleft 
    
    def get_moveright(self):
        return self.moveright
```

Comment: What were you expecting `knobA.get_moveup()` to return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: Why does `get_moveup` call `get_position` instead of returning `self.movup`, and why does `get_position` print a hard-coded string instead of returning `self.position`?

Comment: @chepner: I think that's a question for another day. The OP will get there, but one focused question at a time.

Comment: @chepner  All my functions `get_moveup` , `get_movedown` , etc will call the `get_position ` function first. `get_position` will have 5 lines of GCode(not just the 1 line shown in my example) that will be passed to a command function to move the xyz axis of a 3d printer. So instead of having to write 5 lines of GCode for each function `get_moveup` , `get_movedown` etc., I just have to call the function `get_position`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to make an instance of class knobA:

```py
k = knobA(...)  # suitable parameters elided
k.get_moveup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing any properties of the class, you must create an object of that class:

```
knob = knobA(parameters)
k.get_moveup()
```

That should help you