# Python Error syntax : missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python

i have define i configuration.py file where i have defined a class, this is the code:

```
import logging
from arcpy import SetRasterKeyMetadata
#import ConfigParser
import configparser
import json
import os
import urllib
from datetime import date, timedelta
import requests

class Config(object):
    LOGGING_SECTION = 'logging'
    ARCGIS_REST_SERVICE = 'arcgis-rest-service'
    SAP_SERVICE = 'sap-service'
    FILES_SECTION = 'files'
   _parser = None

def __init__(self):
    self.read_configuration()
    self.token = self.generate_token()


def read_configuration(self):
    project_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    config_file = os.path.join(project_folder, 'config.ini')
    #self._parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    self._parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    self._parser.read(config_file)

........................

 @staticmethod
def generate_token(self):
    print('token')
```

now whe i call the generate_token() function into main.py whit this code:

```
from configuration import Config

from datetime import date, timedelta
import ast

config = Config()
false = False
true = True
null = None



'''
Apply configuration from configuration file
'''

logging.basicConfig(level=config.logging_level)
logger = logging.getLogger('Update')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

if config.logging_file:
    fh = logging.FileHandler(config.logging_file)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

def main():
    message = 'Generazione token Portal for ArcGIS ... '
    logging.info(message)
    token = config.generate_token()
```

I recieve this message error: self.token = self.generate_token()
TypeError: generate_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Why this error? How i can fix?
Thanks

Comment: "staticmethod" decorator and "self" parameter shouldn't be with "generate_token" at the same time.

Comment: As Michael said, a method is either static or has a self positional parameter. Please read about static methods in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: Thanks Michael my error...thanks