# TypeError: a_functin_in_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

Hello I get the self required error bellow but when I try to make an instants of the class I get a 'ClassInstant Name' is not defined error. My code is huge so I can't post it here actually but my 'Class Functons Collings' (ClassInstant.Functions) are used in the class in **init** function. I really don't know what to doo pleas help! THANKS

MY ERROR is:
TypeError: a_functin_in_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

AFTER INSTANT:
NameError: name 'class instant' is not defined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You will also get to debug a lot of your programs if you google the exact error you get. Top result from a search brings you to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh so it turns out I was trying to call the functions by `classname.function` but `self.function` was the correct use inside the class or `__init__` I mean in my case this was the solution another solution I have found before this was using lambda and pass the self argument -->   `lambda: function(self)` but I don't think that this is the best way for it I believe that `self.function` is better.