# Type Error missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' calling the class function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class interface:

```py
class Interface:

    def __init__(self):
        self.users_list = []
        self.admins_list = []
        self.categories_list = []
        self.current_user = ''
        self.user_flag = 0

    @staticmethod
    def start_menu(self):
        print('Add user')
        create_user()
        show_menu()

    @staticmethod
    def create_user(self):
        # code....

    @staticmethod
    def choose_user(self):
        # code...

# call
inter = Interface()
inter.start_menu()
```

And I got the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\79268\Downloads\store.py", line 191, in <module>
inter.start_menu()
TypeError: Interface.start_menu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I can't figure out what the problem is and the advice from this post ([TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)) didn't help?

Comment: Why did you make these methods `@staticmethod`s?

Comment: do you understand what a staticmethod is ? because it seems you don't need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static method use only the namespace of the class. It can use class variables but not the ones specific to an object (`self`).

If all of them are static methods, then you should change the code as follows because there is no notion of `self` in static methods.

```
class Interface:
    users_list = []
    admins_list = []
    categories_list = []
    current_user = ''
    user_flag = 0

    @staticmethod
    def start_menu():
        print('Add user')
        Interface.create_user()
        Interface.show_menu()

    @staticmethod
    def create_user():
        # code....

    @staticmethod
    def choose_user():
        # code...

# call
Interface.start_menu()
```

If you need `self`, make those methods instance methods by removing the `staticmethod` decorator. Also, since you have no arguments for the constructor you can make those variables static, like above.

```
class Interface:

    def __init__(self):
        self.users_list = []
        self.admins_list = []
        self.categories_list = []
        self.current_user = ''
        self.user_flag = 0

    def start_menu(self):
        print('Add user')
        self.create_user()
        self.show_menu()

    def create_user(self):
        # code....

    def choose_user(self):
        # code...

# call
inter = Interface()
inter.start_menu()
```

Due to the above-mentioned constraints, an instance method (method referring to the object, i.e., `self`) can call static methods but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) in the documentation.

As you saved the `users_list` on the instance, I presume you wish to use those variables in other methods. In this case, you don't need a `@staticmethod`.

Refactored `start_menu`:

```
def start_menu(self):
    print('Add user')
    self.create_user()
    self.show_menu()
```