# missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in class

Tags: python

I try to run this code fragment. And I don't get any errors at compile time. But if I run the script. I get this errors:

```
File "c:\Users\engel\Documents\python\code\textFromImages.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Text_from_image:
  File "c:\Users\engel\Documents\python\code\textFromImages.py", line 47, in Text_from_image
    print(filterAnanas())
TypeError: Text_from_image.filterAnanas() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

```
class Text_from_image:
    
    #class variables:
    apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
    ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
    peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'    
    
    def __init__(self) :
        pass        

    def make_pattern(substr):
        return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"

    def get_text_from_image():
        pdfFile = wi(
            filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
        text_factuur_verdi = []

        image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
        imageBlobs = []
        

        for img in image.sequence:
            imgPage = wi(image=img)
            imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

        for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
            text_factuur_verdi.append(text)

        return text_factuur_verdi

    
    def filterAnanas(self):
        self.get_text_from_image()
        return re.findall(self.make_pattern(self.ananas_crownless), self.text_factuur_verdi[0])

    if ananas_crownless:
        print(filterAnanas())
```

So my question is how to fix this?

Comment: `filterAnanas` is a method of the class `Text_from_image`. You can only call the method from an instance of the class, like this 
`Text_from_image().filterAnanas()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Error missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' calling the class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456917/type-error-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self-calling-the-class-func)

Comment: `filterAnanas` is an instance method, you need to have an instance of the `Text_from_image` class in order to call that method. You need to read the basics about how classes and methods in Python work

Comment: if `make_pattern` and `get_text_from_image` don't take a `self` arg they should be decorated with `@staticmethod`

Comment: @wovano I don't think it's a proper dup. The suggested post has it the other way around: `self` is mistakenly added to a static method.

Comment: Ah wait. I didn't read the code to the end. So you're trying to call the method even before the class definition is complete. That's not how it all is supposed to work. Instantiate the class and then call the method. Just what people above say.

Comment: @bereal I think the proposed duplicate contains enough information and examples of how to do this. But yeah, there probably is a better duplicate target. There are many questions about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of bugs in there, I have tried to fix most of them with this...

```
class Text_from_image:


    def __init__(self):
        # class variables:
        self.apples_royal_gala = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'
        self.ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'
        self.peen_waspeen = 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'

    @staticmethod
    def make_pattern(substr):
        return r"(?<=" + substr + r").*?(?P<number>[0-9,.]*)\n"

    @staticmethod
    def get_text_from_image():
        pdfFile = wi(
            filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
        text_factuur_verdi = []

        image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
        imageBlobs = []

        for img in image.sequence:
            imgPage = wi(image=img)
            imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

        for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
            text_factuur_verdi.append(text)

        return text_factuur_verdi

    def filterAnanas(self):
        return re.findall(self.make_pattern(self.ananas_crownless), self.get_text_from_image()[0])

    if self.ananas_crownless:
        print(filterAnanas())
```

Comment: oke, thank you. I only get this error :  if self.ananas_crownless:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: that if statement isn't doing anything, put it in a function which you can call when you want it to execute