# TypeError: Updater.start_polling() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm new to this, for the past few days I've been trying to create a telegram bot, and I keep getting this problem, I have tried to understand the syntax, and I still don't get what it means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with telegram bots but is basic Python. I'd suggest a tutorial for that language first.