# MainWindow.changepage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, customtkinter

I'm trying to program a small login window, but I seem to be stuck on my understanding of classes, functions and attributes. it keeps giving me an error saying `MainWindow.changepage() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

My code is also a bit unorganized because I'm just moving stuff around hoping to understand and fix it.

```
import customtkinter as tk 

class Login(tk.CTkFrame):
     def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        global username
        global password

        username = tk.CTkEntry(self, justify="center", placeholder_text="username", width=200)
        username.pack(pady=20)

        password = tk.CTkEntry(self, justify="center", placeholder_text="password", width=200)
        password.pack()


        button = tk.CTkButton(self, text="Login", command=Check.check_user)
        button.pack(pady=20)

        self.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

class Check():
     def check_user():
        user = username.get()
        passw = password.get()

        if user in users and passw == users[user]:
                print("welcome " + user)
                main = MainWindow
                main.changepage()

        else:
                print("incorrect username or password")

class SecondWindow(tk.CTkFrame):
     def __init__(self, parent):
          super().__init__(parent)
          tk.CTkLabel(self, text="Welcome to jadajada").pack(pady=10,padx=10)
          self.pack(padx = 10, pady=10)

class MainWindow():
     def __init__(self, master):
        mainframe = tk.CTkFrame(master)
        mainframe.pack(padx= 10, pady= 10, fill= "both", expand = True)

        self.index = 0

        self.framelist = [Login(mainframe), SecondWindow(mainframe)]
        self.framelist[1].forget()
     
     def changepage(self):
        self.framelist[self.index].forget()
        self.index = 1
        self.framelist[self.index].tkraise()
        self.framelist[self.index].pack(pady=10,padx=10)

#details
users = dict(namviper="luapnam23", paul="grellmann", luap="nam")

#main window
root = tk.CTk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Login System")
tk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
tk.set_default_color_theme("green")

#main systems
window = MainWindow(root)

#mainloops
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
class Check():
     def check_user():
        user = username.get()
        passw = password.get()

        if user in users and passw == users[user]:
                print("welcome " + user)
                main = MainWindow # error here
                main.changepage()

        else:
                print("incorrect username or password")
```

I'm pretty sure you meant to instantiate (create an instance of a class). For this you need to add parentheses after `MainWindow` and pass the proper parameters such that the line becomes `MainWindow(root)`. You may need to rework your code so that you can pass the correct parameter. An alternative would be to pass the MainWindow object (`main`) itself to Check.check_user.

Other note, your Check class is useless as it stores no data and only has one function. This could simply be a function.