# How to fix python logging error "TypeError: setLevel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'level'"?

Tags: python

I am trying to use a simple logger in python (3.9.6) to log out to the terminal and to format the logging with some timestamp etc. as follows (following [this example](https://sematext.com/blog/python-logging/)):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a file handler
handler = logging.StreamHandler 
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a logging format and add that to the logger
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

But when running this correctly-seeming code I get an error

```
TypeError: setLevel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'level'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `handler` is a _class_, not an instance.

Comment: I am following an example in a link (added)

Comment: That resource also refers to `Logging.waring`, so maybe you should find one that doesn't suck!

Comment: @jonrsharpe So you have no idea how to fix it then?

Comment: You _instantiate_ the handler before trying to call methods on it, but likely that just gets you to the next error in what you've copy-pasted. This is a dupe of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17534345/3001761 as written. Try https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html instead.

Comment: Alex, he's saying you should probably look for a better tutorial given that that one is riddled with typos.

Answer (score 1):

The example on the referenced webpage is incorrect. The fixed working code is as follows:

```
# Set up the logging monster
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a file handler
handler = logging.StreamHandler() # Here the brackets were missing
#handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a logging format and add that to the logger
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score -3):

you must use:

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!')
```