# ArgumentParser.add_argument raises AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prefix_chars'

Tags: python, exception, argparse

When I run my program, I immediately get an `AttributeError` when it's setting up the argument parser:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 55, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('--select-equal', '--equal', nargs=2, metavar=[ 'COLUMN', 'VALUE' ], action='append', dest='filter_equality_keys_and_values', default=[], help='Only return rows for which this column is exactly equal to this value.')
  File "…/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/argparse.py", line 1346, in add_argument
    chars = self.prefix_chars
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prefix_chars'
```

Well, that sounds reasonable. `str`s indeed don't have a `prefix_chars` attribute. Clearly the exception message is correct.

Except I can't parse arguments, or even get *to* parsing arguments, because of this exception. Why is this throwing an exception? Why is it trying to get `prefix_chars` of a `str` in the first place? The exception is coming from inside the Python module; is this a bug in Python or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are the chances that two people made the same typo mistake in two days :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76758408/expected-type-actionscontainer-got-str-instead

Answer (score 1):

It is, in fact, something I was doing wrong.

The clue is that the method is trying to access an attribute of an object that doesn't have such an attribute—and it's trying to do so on `self`.

The first argument to my call to `add_argument` is indeed a string (`'--select-equal'`). The only way that string could end up being `self` is if I were calling `add_argument` on the ArgumentParser *class* and not an ArgumentParser *object*.

And indeed, scrolling up a couple lines in my own code, there's the problem:

```
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
```

I need to instantiate ArgumentParser, which means calling the class (`ArgumentParser()`), not just stash the class in a variable.

For want of a `()`, the exception was thrown.